# Ola Hallengren with database mirroring

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, mirroring, maintenance, ola-hallengren

I am about to setup [Ola Hallengrens](http://ola.hallengren.com/) database maintenance plan. We have our database mirrored and I was just wanting to know if I need to run the script on both my Sql Server instances or only the primary?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I recommend that you have the jobs enabled and scheduled on both servers and with the same configurations. Databases that are in a mirror role will automatically be skipped. There are checks for that in the script.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in and confirming. Appreciate your excellent scripts :-)

Comment: Do you really think you're qualified to speak on this matter? ;)

Comment: Can someone verify the authenticity of this user?

Comment: Do you even exist? I've always thought you're just a brilliant bunch of maintenance scripts :-).

Comment: @OlaHallengren - sorry for the misunderstanding. We were just so excited to see you here that we turned into primary school kids.

Comment: @swasheck Speak for yourself, but I was more excited than a little school girl.

Answer (score 7):

For now just run it on the Primary database server.

When you do a failover, you can run it on the mirrored server.

e.g when you deploy it on mirrored server, you (refer to: http://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html)

```
EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseBackup
@Databases = 'SYSTEM_DATABASES', -- when failover, change it to ALL
@Directory = 'C:\Backup',
@BackupType = 'LOG',
@Verify = 'Y',
@ChangeBackupType = 'Y',
@CleanupTime = 24
```